# A very simple html table

Tags: html, html-table

I need to make the table like below:

[image]

Here is my code, logically everything seems to be written correctly, but if you remove the extra cell, then everything breaks. in what there can be an error?

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td>Five</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Six</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>Seven</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Eight</td>
    <td>Extra</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nine</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Liam I think that, by attachment means the image shown.. maybe..

Comment: Yes, the question can be very easy, but I can not figure it out ... How to make the same table as in the picture?

Comment: @Liam I understood the asker just fine from the original post.. They posted their goal and what they had attempted. What I don't understand is why you removed their code snippet that allowed people to quickly see what the asker had attempted.

Comment: @Liam : OK, fair enough, but I salute you and the others for helping make this intelligible. Not everyone has English as a first language. Hopefully OP will learn to use google translate to write their postings in the future. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are - i just added a second line of text to the higher/merged cells, but it (only) works without that "Extra" cell:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #444;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td>Five</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Six<br>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>Seven<br>X</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Eight<br>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nine</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```